# unexpected behavior on casting char to int

Tags: c, type-conversion

I'm struggling with an unexpected behavior on casting a `char` to an `unsigned int`. Sometimes the remaining bits are filled with 0 and other times with 1.

On a simple program tested on gcc 4.9.2

```
unsigned int test_1 = 0x01;
unsigned int test_2 = (char)(0x01);
unsigned int test_3 = 0xc3;
unsigned int test_4 = (char)(0xc3);
```

The output is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 
00000000 00000000 00000000 11000011 
11111111 11111111 11111111 11000011
```

I expected to have "blank" bits filled with 0 and and not 1.

Expected output :

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001 
00000000 00000000 00000000 11000011 
00000000 00000000 00000000 11000011
```

---

Full code below :

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define binary_p( x ) printBits(sizeof(x),&x)

void printBits(size_t const size, void const * const ptr)
{
    unsigned char *b = (unsigned char*) ptr;
    unsigned char byte;
    int i, j;

    for (i=size-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        for (j=7;j>=0;j--)
        {
            byte = (b[i] >> j) & 1;
            printf("%u", byte);
        }

            printf(" ");
    }
     puts("");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    unsigned int test_1 = 0x01;
    unsigned int test_2 = (char) (0x01);
    unsigned int test_3 = 0xc3;
    unsigned int test_4 = (char) (0xc3);

    binary_p(test_1);
    binary_p(test_2);
    binary_p(test_3);
    binary_p(test_4);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `c/c++` is UB..

Comment: Try `(unsigned char)` instead! Is it the same result?

Comment: You compiler does the right thing according to the standard, but apparently not according to what you wanted. What did you want to happen instead?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Which one do you use? How do you print? Provide a [mcve] and read [ask].

Comment: What behavior do you expect and why?

Comment: It seems like `char` is signed, and the conversion to `unsigned int` is sign extended. If you convert to a signed `int` instead, you should see the same negative value for both the `int` and the `char`. You could use `unsigned char` instead, as Iharob suggested above.

Comment: char is signed, so (char)0xc3 gives -61, then -61 converted to unsigned which gives you what you see in the output. Negatives usually stores as [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)

Comment: @MagnusHoff: The **cast** is not sign-extended, but the preceeding conversion to `int` is.

Comment: @em2er: If you mean "`char` on your platform is signed", you are right. Otherwise you are wrong.

Comment: Looks like C, I removed the C++ tag. And how do you know `unsigned char` has 8 bits?

Comment: @Olaf yes, you are completely right.

Comment: @slava I expected tho have "blank" bites filled with 0 and and not 1

Comment: @Corrosif What is the _value_ of `(char)(0xc3)` on your platform?  Try `printf("%d\n", (char)(0xc3));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case:

```
unsigned int test_3 = 0xc3;
```

The constant `0xc3` has type `int`.  It's value (195) is in the positive range of an `int`, so when it is converted to `unsigned int` via the assignment, it retains that value.

As for this case:

```
unsigned int test_4 = (char)(0xc3);
```

The value is first cast to a `char`.  Assuming a `char` is 8 bits and 2's compliment representation is used for negative numbers, this representation falls into the negative range (-61).  So when it is converted to a larger type, the extra bits added are set to 1 to retain the same negative value.

Comment: Detail: Even if "a `char` is 8 bits and 2's compliment representation", the conversion of 195 to an 8-bit signed `char` is _implementation-defined_ behavior (or a signal is raised) .  The common, though not specified, ID behavior  results in `(char)(0xc3)` --> `-61`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(unsigned char)(0xc3)
(unsigned char)(0xc3)
```

instead of

```
 (char)(0x01)
 (char)(0xc3)
```

that should do the trick